# bash alias to run command (with args) if exist or run another command (with args) otherwise

Tags: linux, bash, alias

I want to setup bash alias that runs `command_1 [args]` if `command_1` exists and "runnable", or runs `command_2 [args]` if `command_1` does not exists or not "runnable". `[args]` are not known in advance and could be empty or not. `[args]` are the same for `command_1` and `command_2`.

In the terminal I can action like this:

```
command_1 --version >/dev/null 2>&1
[ "$?" = "0" ] && command_1 args || command_2 args
```

The first line outputs nothing, the second checks exit code (`$?`) of first line. So if `command_1 --version` exits with "0" status code (without errors), I run `command_1 args`, else (if `command_1` doesn't exists or is broken by any other reason, e.g. user don't have relevant permissions to run `command_1`) I run `command_2 args`.

How to turn this into bash alias?

If there were no `[args]` I could use something like this:

```
alias my_alias='command_1 --version >/dev/null 2>&1 ; [ "$?" = "0" ] && command_1 || command_2'
```

But in this case if I run `my_alias args` and `command_1` exists, It will run `command_1` without args. How to add `[args]` into my alias for both `command_1` and `command_2`?

Comment: Use a function.

Comment: An alias does not take parameters. It just expands the command word by the alias definition.

Comment: As the bash IRC channel's alias factoid has said for over a decade now: "If you have to ask, use a function instead".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/), because an `alias` is a poor match for the purpose. Use a function instead:

```bash
resolve_command() {
  if type 'command_1' 1>&2; then
    'command_1' "$@"
  elif type 'command_2' 1>&2; then
    'command_2' "$@"
  else
    echo 'Nope. Blah.' 1>&2
    return 11
  fi
}

resolve_command "${some_args[@]}"
```

This can be easily extended to probe for an arbitrary number of different commands.

```bash
resolve_command() {
  local -ar commands=('command_1' 'command_2' 'command_3')
  local cmd
  for cmd in "${commands[@]}"; do
    if type "$cmd" 1>&2; then
      "$cmd" "$@"
      return
    fi
  done
  echo 'Nope. Blah.' 1>&2
  return 11
}

resolve_command "${some_args[@]}"
```

Comment: `which` isn't an appropriate choice in bash -- unlike zsh where it really is built-in, it's an external command, not built into the shell. The POSIX equivalent is `if command -v command_1 >/dev/null 2>&1; then ...`, or the bash-only equivalent is `if type command_1 >/dev/null 2>&1`

Comment: Also think about using a different stand-in, since `command` itself is a command that's built into the shell (which is how I'm using it above -- when I say `command` I actually mean `command`, not `your-command-here`, whereas `command_1` is a `your-command-here`-type standin). Using the name `command` to also mean "insert your own thing here" is thus confusing.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Edited. As for the `1>&2`, that’s intentional (to see what it resolved to without interfering with the actual command’s stdout). Of course the OP can go for a `>/dev/null` if this is not desirable. (Actually, `type` outputs something on failure, so an extra `2>&1` would be needed too to silence it.)